# Hydration children mismatch in <div>: server rendered element contains fewer child nodes than client vdom

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, slick.js

Hydration children mismatch in : server rendered element contains fewer child nodes than client vdom..

Nuxt Link Not Working When Use It Within Slick

Its duplicate this content without slick..
I searched alot..
What's the problem..
I use it as a Component

Nuxt3

```
<div class="products-tabs">
    <!-- tab -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="products-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-1">
            <!-- product -->
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="/img/product01.png" alt="">
                    <div class="product-label">
                        <span class="sale">-30%</span>
                        <span class="new">NEW</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-body">
                    <p class="product-category">Category</p>
                    <h3 class="product-name"><router-link to="product">Product</router-link></h3>
                    <h4 class="product-price">$980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del></h4>
                    <div class="product-rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-btns">
                        <button class="add-to-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to
                                wishlist</span></button>
                        <button class="add-to-compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to
                                compare</span></button>
                        <button class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="tooltipp">quick
                                view</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                    <button class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /product -->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by commenting out the empty components.

[image: Component commented]

and where its called

[image: Called]

Comment: I have no empty components ..
Just a HTML Section that have slider
and the problem still exists

Answer (score -1):

Hydration children mismatch error is mainly due to mismatch between the server-rendered HTML and the client-side virtual DOM (Vue components). The number of child nodes in the server element is different from the client-side. Check the the Vue component structure.

Comment: Check it for what?